# How to store data where the columns need to be different everytime?

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am writing a Crud application to store my client information. However, each client requires different data to be stored. E.g. One client may require data relating to a vehicle stored whilst another requires information regarding fishing rods stored. I have many new clients each week and have about 100 current ones. Is there anyway around creating a new table for each client?

EDIT: Using Access 2010

Comment: Need more information, but probably not, HOWEVER it depends on the software your using against the DB. In this scenario the software would create the dbwith the column name it needed for example, a shopping cart site would have a configuration page that allowed the user to define the properties of the item being sold and create the needed columns and then create a configuration file to map the column names at run time. There is a more complex way to do it and it is technically better, but I'm about to reach the limit on a comment so I can't describe it. So really it depends on your software.

Comment: Can't you *generalize* certain aspects? Ok, one customer has vehicles, the other fishing rods - can't you extract the common information for these into a "Products" table and just store the extra, different attributes separately?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I am using Access for this. Updated question with this now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store information on different products in different columns! You must [normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In your case you would need to have at least 3 tables

```
Table Customer
--------------
CustomerID (PK)
Name
Address
etc.

Table Product
-------------
ProductID (PK)
Name
Price
etc.

Table CustomerItem
------------------
CustomerItemID (PK)
CustomerID (FK)
ProductID (FK)
Date
Remarks
etc.
```

If you are storing orders (or invoices) you must replace the `CustomerItem` table by the following two tables:

```
Table Order
-----------
OrderID (PK)
CustomerID (FK)
Date
etc.

Table OrderItem
---------------
OrderID (PK, FK)
ProductID (PK, FK)
Quantity
Price
etc.
```

(PK) denotes primary key columns, (FK) foreign key columns.

The database diagram looks like this:

```
Customer
  1 |     n
    +------> Order                      Product
              1 |     n             n     | 1
                +------> OrderItem <------+
```

This enables you to store an arbitrary number of informations per customer by always using the same columns. Instead of using different columns, you just add new related records (e.g. a new order or a new order item in an existing order).

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with this data?

If you told me that one client wants to store the item price, and that he wants you to later multiply the item price by the quantity in inventory to get total inventory value, and another client wants you to store the altitude at which a plane is flying, and he wants you to compare altitudes of different planes in the same area as part of a collision avoidance system, I'd say that you have two very distinct fields, probably two distinct tables. You need to create separate fields and/or tables for them. If you have 100 clients who all have totally different requirements, like one wants a payroll system and another wants a retail sales system and another wants a system to monitor temperature and pressure of his laboratory experiments, I wouldn't try to somehow cram all of these wildly different things into one database.

But if you mean, both clients are retailers, and one sells vehicles that have a description and a price and a quantity on hand, and the other sells fishing rods that have a description and a price and a quantity on hand, and you do pretty much the same things with the data from both, then the only issue is giving suitably general names to the fields. If you looked at the requirements for the system for the car dealer and your thought was, "I'll create a table I call 'vehicle_inventory' with a column called 'vehicle_description'", and now you find yourself creating a very similar system for a fishing rod dealer, the only real issue might be that "vehicle_inventory" and "vehicle_description" were too specific, you could have called them "inventory" and "item_description" and then it works in both cases.

If this isn't responsive to your question, please be more specific about just what the problem is.